# AWS Cloudformation: error: instance Fn::GetAtt undefined AWS Scalable EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

**Cloud Formation AWS Scalable EC2 Problem**

Using AWS CloudFormation YAML to create resource stack with EC2, RDS database, ELB Load Balancer. This code is a design solution that will provide for a base scalable EC2 for subnets and LoadBalancer to handle higher traffic with a relational database with AWS RDB using S3 Storage

1. Is this correct to have the design of Subnet2 have a EC2 instance? Is it better or even required to have a ELB Load Balancer's associated with all subnet1/2 to be listeners on, or using, the application listener. Is it correct to design the EC2 Security Group to be associated with the DB (MyRDS) instance and have relationships associated with S3 buckets and S3 bucket policy? Is is more correct migrate the EC2 Security Group / S3 bucket/policy to be moved, and associated with each and every subnet/EC2 instance?

A final point is an unseen template error, so running this design I have An unseen Template error on instance of Fn::GetAtt in resource ELBSecurityGroup, the references to Fn::GetAtt has been already removed from ELBSecurityGroup.

**AWS Designer**

[image]

**Error in ELBSecurityGroup**

```
Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource ELBSecurityGroup
```

**CloudFormation Script code**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Parameters:

  DBName:
    Default: mydb
    Description: My database
    Type: String
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '64'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'

  DBUsername:
    Type: String
    Description: Master username for the RDS instance
    Default: admin

  DBPassword:
    Type: String
    NoEcho: true
    Description: Master password for the RDS instance
    Default: password

  DBInstanceClass:
    Default: db.m5.large
    Description: DB instance class
    Type: String

  DBAllocStore:
    Default: '50'
    Description: The size of the database (GiB)
    Type: Number
    MinValue: '20'
    MaxValue: '65536'

  DBInstance:
    Default: DBInstance
    Description: My database instance
    Type: String
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '63'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'

Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: VPC

  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: 'aws--s3--bucket'

  IGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: VPC Internet Gateway

  AGate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  Subnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.20.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Private Subnet 1

  Subnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.30.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Public Subnet 2

  RouteTbl:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Public Route Table

  Route:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTbl
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  SubRoute1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTbl

  SubRoute2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref Subnet2
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTbl

  ELBSecGrp:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: ELB Security Group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 22
        ToPort: 22
        CidrIp: 10.0.0.222/24

  SSHSecGrp:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      GroupDescription: Security group egress
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - CidrIp: 127.0.0.111/32
          IpProtocol: "-1"
 
  EC2SecGrp:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: EC2 Security Group
      GroupName: aws-security-grp
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80
      SourceSecurityGroupId:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 22
        ToPort: 22
        CidrIp: 10.0.0.333/24

  EC2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref EC2SecGrp
      SubnetId: !Ref Subnet1
      KeyName: EC2
      UserData: 
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
          yum update -y
          yum install -y httpd
          systemctl start httpd
          systemctl enable httpd
          #echo "<h1>Hello from Region us-east-2b</h1>" > /var/www/html/index.html

  S3BuckPol:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref EC2SecGrp
      KeyName: S3BucketPol
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 's3:*'
            Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${S3Bucket}/*'
            Principal:
              AWS: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:user/@matthew'

  EC2TgtGrp:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 15
      HealthyThresholdCount: 5
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: '200'
      Name: EC2TargetGroup
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      TargetGroupAttributes:
      - Key: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds
        Value: '20'
      Targets:
      - Id: !Ref EC2
        Port: 80
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 3

  LoadBal:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Name: aws-elb-load-balance
      Scheme: internet-facing
      Subnets:
      - !Ref Subnet2
      SecurityGroups:
        - !GetAtt ELBSecurityGroup.GroupId

  ALBListen:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref EC2TgtGrp
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref LoadBal
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP

  MyRDS:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
    Properties:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: !Ref DBInstance
      DBName: !Ref DBName
      DBInstanceClass: !Ref DBInstanceClass
      AllocatedStorage: !Ref DBAllocStore
      Engine: MySQL
      MasterUsername: !Ref DBUsername
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref DBPassword
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref EC2SecGrp
      KeyName: MyRDS

Outputs:
  EC2InstanceId:
    Description: InstanceId of EC2 instance
    Value: !Ref EC2

  S3BucketName:
    Description: S3 bucket
    Value: !Ref S3Bucket

  DBInstanceId:
    Description: DBInstanceIdentifier of RDS instance
    Value: !Ref DBInstance
```

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why do you get the error?

Comment: It baffles me:  No evidenced of Fn::GetAtt command exists in entire scripts

Comment: Not sure what you mean? You use `!GetAtt` in your template.

Answer (score 1):

`ELBSecurityGroup` resource does not exist. Probably it should be `ELBSecGrp`:

```
      SecurityGroups:
        - !GetAtt ELBSecGrp.GroupId
```